# Does a vaulted ceiling roof need venting?

Tags: roof, ventilation

I'm buying a house in Colorado, and the house has a vaulted (cathedral) ceiling such that both the plywood sheathing and the ceiling sheetrock are attached to opposite sides of the rafters, i.e. no attic.  My inspector said it needs ventilation (ridge vent + soffit vents).  The roofer who did the job for the sellers says it does not.  Does such a roof need venting?  It's a passive solar home without a lot of cooling ability.  My concern is heat buildup during the summer and potential moisture build-up.  The roof is only 5 years old and one of the sheets of plywood has already blistered significantly.

Comment: Is it vaulted or a cathedral ceiling? If cathedral, I'm not seeing as what is going to need vented? I take it there is insulation between the sheetrock and the roofing material?

Comment: Yes - cathedral.  How can you tell if there's insulation in there w/o taking off a piece of plywood or part of the ceiling inside?

Comment: Do you know how it's insulated?  Fiberglass? Sprayed foam? Packed cellulose?

Comment: @Comintern - I have no idea, nor do I have any idea on how to find out without taking either part of the ceiling or part of the roof off.